# IJulia for Julia v0.7

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I tried building the latest (dev) version of Julia (v0.7) and want to use this kernel from Jupyter Notebook. When I tried running 
`Pkg.add("IJulia")` and building the module, the build failed. The errors I get are along the lines of

```
 Error: ------------------------------------------------------------
│ # Build failed for IJulia
│   exception =
│    LoadError: UndefVarError: JULIA_HOME not defined
│    Stacktrace:
│     [1] uv_error at ./libuv.jl:68 [inlined]
│     [2] unlink(::String) at ./file.jl:526
│     [3] #rm#9(::Bool, ::Bool, ::Function, ::String) at ./file.jl:149
│     [4] #rm at ./<missing>:0 [inlined]
│     [5] #installkernel#2(::String, ::Function, ::String) at /Users/myuser/.julia/v0.7/IJulia/deps/kspec.jl:117
│     [6] installkernel(::String) at /Users/myuser/.julia/v0.7/IJulia/deps/kspec.jl:36
│     [7] top-level scope at /Users/myuser/.julia/v0.7/IJulia/deps/build.jl:75
│     [8] include at ./boot.jl:295 [inlined]
│     [9] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1067
│     [10] include at ./sysimg.jl:26 [inlined]
│     [11] include(::String) at ./loading.jl:1101
│     [12] top-level scope
│     [13] eval at ./boot.jl:298 [inlined]
│     [14] eval at ./sysimg.jl:71 [inlined]
│     [15] evalfile(::String, ::Array{String,1}) at ./loading.jl:1096 (repeats 2 times)
│     [16] #2 at ./none:15 [inlined]
│     [17] cd(::getfield(, Symbol("##2#5")){String}, ::String) at ./file.jl:70
│     [18] (::getfield(, Symbol("##1#3")))(::IOStream) at ./none:14
│     [19] #open#318(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::getfield(, Symbol("##1#3")), ::String, ::Vararg{String,N} where N) at ./iostream.jl:369
│     [20] open(::Function, ::String, ::String) at ./iostream.jl:367
│     [21] top-level scope
│     [22] eval at ./boot.jl:298 [inlined]
│     [23] eval(::Module, ::Expr) at ./sysimg.jl:71
│     [24] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:309
│     [25] _start() at ./client.jl:448
│    in expression starting at /Users/myuser/.julia/v0.7/IJulia/deps/build.jl:104
└ @ Main none:18
```

Is it reasonable to post this as an issue on the github, or are the issues only supposed to be for the stable release v0.6?

Comment: In general you shouldn't expect packages to work on julia master. In this particular case I think you have to wait for https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/pull/623 to be merged.

Answer (score 0):

In the upcoming Julia v0.7, the variable `JULIA_HOME` (from the Base module) has been renamed to `Sys.BINDIR` [1].

After having a look to the repository, it seems that they are currently porting IJulia to version 0.7. I don't think that it hurts to file an issue given now that you have the solution how to fix this particular issue. Also  this particular error message does not show in continuous integration builds [2]. However, there a probably many other issues given the long list of changes [1] and since version 0.7 has not yet been released. Thus do not expect IJulia to to work with Julia v0.7 (dev) after this change.

[1] https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/NEWS.md

[2] https://travis-ci.org/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/jobs/336988585